# error: Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'view' , while trying to load share pdf getting an error

Tags: ios, swift

[STORYBOARD VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpJUG.png) THIS IS HOW THE VIEW CONTROLLER LOOKS LIKE
In a method of a UIView extension, I get the error:

> UIView has no member view

The error is on the line:

```
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
```

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension ViewController {
 // Export pdf from Save pdf in drectory and return pdf file path
    func exportAsPdfFromView() -> String {
        getDirectoryPath()
        getImage()
        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.colors = [
            UIColor.red.cgColor,
            UIColor.green.cgColor
        ]

        //bounds = CGRect(x: originalBounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: self.scrollView.contentSize.height)
        let pdfPageFrame = view.bounds
        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageFrame, nil)
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageFrame, nil)
        guard let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return "" }
        layer.render(in: pdfContext)
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        return self.saveViewPdf(data: pdfData)


    }

    // Save pdf file in document directory
    func saveViewPdf(data: NSMutableData) -> String {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let docDirectoryPath = paths[0]
        print(docDirectoryPath)
        let pdfPath = docDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent("viewPdf.pdf")

        if data.write(to: pdfPath, atomically: true) {
            return pdfPath.path
            print("PDF written at path \(pdfPath.path)")
           // let data = try? Data(contentsOf: pdfPath!)
            //let str = String(bytes: data!, encoding: .utf8)
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
    func getImage(){
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let imagePAth = (self.getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("viewPdf.pdf")
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePAth){
            print("HI")
            print(imagePAth)
        //imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePAth)
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePAth){
                let documento = NSData(contentsOfFile: imagePAth)
                let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [documento!], applicationActivities: nil)
                activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
                .presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else {
                print("document was not found")
            }
        }else{
            print("No Image")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why post so much code when the error is on one line (which you have not pointed out at all)?

Comment: Change `...= self.view` to `... = self`. `self` is already a UIView in an extension to `UIView`.

Comment: Hi Maddy thanks for your quick response.when I tried to correct with the feedback given iam facing another issue :Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'presentViewController'; did you mean 'inputViewController'?@rmaddy

Comment: Since you keep trying to use method from UIViewController in your extension then maybe your extension should be on UIViewController instead of UIView.

Answer (score 0):

You can't [present](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-presentviewcontroller) a `UIActivityViewController` from a `UIView` object. Create a `UIViewController` `extension` method like this and call it from any view controller

```
extension UIViewController {
    func getImage(){
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let imagePAth = (self.getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("viewPdf.pdf")
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePAth){
            print("HI")
            print(imagePAth)
            //imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePAth)
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePAth) {
                let documento = NSData(contentsOfFile: imagePAth)
                let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [documento!], applicationActivities: nil)
                activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
                self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else {
                print("document was not found")
            }
        }else{
            print("No Image")
        }
    }
    func getDirectoryPath() -> String {
        ///
        return string
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Rajesh thanks for  your help and suggestion .Iam really stuck with this homework .Now Iam getting an issue as :Use of unresolved identifier 'bounds'.if you want I can share the extension code @RajeshKumar R

Comment: now the code is succeeded.with an error when I tap on generate pdf I get an error.Thread 1: signal SIGABRT @RajeshKumar R

Comment: @coder In which line it is crashing and what is the error in log?

Comment: 2019-05-11 13:02:30.478457+1000 PDFFileGeneration[68610:1820718] -[UIView view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f95e1511090
2019-05-11 13:02:30.484373+1000 PDFFileGeneration[68610:1820718] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f95e1511090' @RajeshKumar R

Comment: In appdelegate @RajeshKumar R

Comment: @coder Use Exception BreakPoint to find which line makes the app crash

Comment: the app is getting crashed after this line in the extension part -  let pdfPageFrame = view.bounds after this line @RajeshKumar R

Comment: @coder try UIScreen.main.bounds instead of view.bounds